# Задать внешнюю границу таблицы

Tags: html, css

Внешняя граница в коде указана другим цветом, но перекрывается границами внутренних ячеек.

```css
.sho_table-2 {
  border: 1px solid #2a2b33;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sho_table-2 td {
  border: 1px solid #e9e9ea;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.sho_table-2 tr:hover {
  background: #edeeee;
}
```

```html
<table class="sho_table-2">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Производитель&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Xiaomi&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Синхронизация с устройством&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WiFi + Blootooth 4.0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Тип&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Диагностические (SMART)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Вес&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1.9 кг&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

нужно, чтобы внешняя не перекрывалась.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `outline` или границу большей толщины, чем у ячеек.

```css
.sho_table-2 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sho_table-2 td {
  border: 1px solid #e9e9ea;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.sho_table-2 tr:hover {
  background: #edeeee;
}
```

```html
<table class="sho_table-2">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Производитель&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Xiaomi&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Синхронизация с устройством&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WiFi + Blootooth 4.0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Тип&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Диагностические (SMART)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Вес&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1.9 кг&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```